# List is not visible in Ext.Container even though I added layout and flex properties

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Playing around with Sencha Touch 2.0 and have stumbled upon a problem. I want a list to show in my Ext.Container but nothing is happening.

**My class (LoggedInView.js)**

```
Ext.define("GS.view.LoggedInView", {
extend: "Ext.Container",
config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [{
        xtype: "toolbar",
        docked: "top",
        title: "Pågående anbud"
    },{ 
        xtype: 'list',
        itemTpl: '{name}',
        flex: 1,
        store : 'Auction'
    }]
}
```

});

**My Store (Auction.js)**

```
Ext.define('GS.store.Auction', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

config: {
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['name'],
    data: [
        {name: 'test1'},
        {name: 'test2'},
        {name: 'test3'},
        {name: 'test4'},
    ]
},
```

});

**My application (app.js)**

```
Ext.application({
name: 'GS',

requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox'
],

views: ['Main', 'LoggedInView'],

stores: ['Auction'],
....etc...
```

What am I doing wrong here? I get the toolbar rendered correctly but the list is not showing.

**EDIT**

Alos attached my (main.js)

```
// The login button
var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Logga in',
    minHeight: '45px',
    handler: function (b, e) {
        var form = Ext.getCmp('register');
        form.submit({
            url: 'URL HERE',
            method: 'POST', 
            success: function (frm, res)  {
                 var paneltab = Ext.create('GS.view.LoggedInView');
                 Ext.getCmp('register').destroy();
                 Ext.Viewport.add(paneltab);
            },
            failure: function (frm, res) {
                alert('Form no submit!');
            }
        });
    }
});

var loginForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    id: 'register',
    frame:true, 
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'userName',
                    placeHolder : 'Användarnamn'
                },
                {   
                    xtype: 'passwordfield',
                    name : 'password',
                    placeHolder : 'Lösenord'
                }
            ]
        },
        {   
            xtype: 'container',      
            items: [button]
        },
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `fullscreen: true` to your view config

**My class (LoggedInView.js)**

```
Ext.define("GS.view.LoggedInView", {
extend: "Ext.Container",
config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [{
        xtype: "toolbar",
        docked: "top",
        title: "Pågående anbud"
    },{ 
        xtype: 'list',
        itemTpl: '{name}',
        flex: 1,
        store : 'Auction'
    }]
}
});
```

Your code in senchafiddle: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#HcaOD

EDIT:

In your Main.js you don't define your Main View, so it can't be created in app.js

**Reworked Main.js**

```
Ext.define('GS.view.Main', {
    extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
    config : {
        fullscreen : true,
        id : 'register',
        frame : true,
        items : [{
            xtype : 'fieldset',
            items : [{
                xtype : 'textfield',
                name : 'userName',
                placeHolder : 'Användarnamn'
            }, {
                xtype : 'passwordfield',
                name : 'password',
                placeHolder : 'Lösenord'
            }]
        }, {

            xtype : 'button',
            text : 'Logga in',
            minHeight : '45px',
            handler : function(b, e) {
                var form = Ext.getCmp('register');
                form.submit({
                    url : 'http://testurl.com',
                    method : 'POST',
                    success : function(frm, res) {
                        var paneltab = Ext
                                .create('GS.view.LoggedInView');
                        Ext.getCmp('register').destroy();
                        Ext.Viewport.add(paneltab);
                    },
                    failure : function(frm, res) {
                        alert('Form no submit!');
                    }
                });
            }

        }]
    }
});
```

A additional problem ist, that the post method doesn't work, because it's not submitted, so it alerts "Form no submit!". But when you put your success code in the failure function, the list is shown.

However i recommend you to put the button handler in a controller.

The button Code then look like this:

```
{
    xtype : 'button',
    text : 'Logga in',
    minHeight : '45px',
    action: 'submitFormAction'
}
```

**Controller.js**

```
Ext.define('GS.controller.Controller', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',    
    config : {   
        control : {
            'button[action="submitFormAction"]' : {
                tap : 'submitForm'
            },
        }
    },
    submitForm : function() {
        var form = Ext.getCmp('register');
        form.submit({
            url : 'http://testurl.com',
            method : 'POST',
            success : function(frm, res) {
                 var paneltab = Ext.create('GS.view.LoggedInView');
                Ext.getCmp('register').destroy();
                Ext.Viewport.add(paneltab);                
            },
            failure : function(frm, res) {
                alert('Form no submit!'); 
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Then you must add the controller in your **app.js** with  `controllers:['Controller'],`.

Working senchafiddle: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#HcaOD#pArtn

Comment: That works...although you changed the app.js launch function. Mine looks like this: launch: function() { Ext.create('GS.view.Main'); } which creates a login form panel. The success function of the login is : 
var paneltab = Ext.create('GS.view.LoggedInView');
Ext.getCmp('register').destroy();
Ext.Viewport.add(paneltab);

I guess the issue lies there? Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check for problems in the console? I think the Component with the ID 'register' can't be found and so it can't be destroyed and the code stops before adding it to the Viewport. Try in your success function of the login: Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('GS.view.LoggedInView')); If that doesn't work, pleas post your code of the Main/Login view.

Comment: Console error says that the Main.js is not declared as a class.

Comment: Found a solution to the problem :) it was the Main.js. Will post it here.

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks. The controller is the best way!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found the solution to this problem. It was my Main.js class that was not defined. Restructured the code some and voila!

```
Ext.define('GS.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        id: 'register',
        frame:true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'userName',
                    placeHolder : 'Användarnamn'
                },
                {   
                    xtype: 'passwordfield',
                    name : 'password',
                    placeHolder : 'Lösenord'
                }
            ]
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Logga in',
            minHeight: '45px',
            handler: function (b, e) {
                var form = Ext.getCmp('register');
                form.submit({
                    url: 'MY URL HERE',
                    method: 'POST', 
                    success: function (frm, res)  {
                         var paneltab = Ext.create('GS.view.LoggedInView');
                         Ext.getCmp('register').destroy();
                         Ext.Viewport.add(paneltab);
                    },
                    failure: function (frm, res) {
                        alert('Form no submit!');
                    }
                });
            }
        }]
    }
});
```